Deploy of a reveal.js presentation using github pages its not loading the html
I'm trying to deploy a Reveal.js presentation using the external plugin, https://github.com/janschoepke/reveal_externa.
The thing is that when deployed, it shows the following error:

To my low understanding, this means it's not being able to find my html sources, I've tried some basic suggestions, like changing the way i wrote my paths and such but nothing has worked so far.
I'll add a link to my repo just in case. HERE
Also, here is the distribution of my folders, the html files are in the presentation folder.

And this is my index html:
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">

        <title>Curso OpenGL</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/reset.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/reveal.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/theme/serif.css">

        <!-- Theme used for syntax highlighted code -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="plugin/highlight/monokai.css">
        
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="reveal">
            <div class="slides">
                <section data-external="presentation/title.html"></section>

                <section data-external="presentation/content.html"></section>

                <section data-external-replace="presentation/basics/introduction.html"></section>

                <section data-external-replace="presentation/development enviroment/DE.html"></section>
                
                <section data-external-replace="presentation/fundaments/fundamentals.html"></section>

                <section data-external-replace="presentation/basicFigures/BF.html"></section>
                
                <section data-external-replace="presentation/geometricTransformations/gt.html"></section>
                
                <section data-external-replace="presentation/camara/pc.html"></section>

                <section data-external-replace="presentation/shadows/is.html"></section>

                <section data-external-replace="presentation/texture/texture.html"></section>

                <section data-external-replace="presentation/animation/animation.html"></section>

                <section data-external-replace="presentation/user/userInteraction.html"></section>
                
            </div>
        </div>

        <script src="dist/reveal.js"></script>
        <script src="plugin/notes/notes.js"></script>
        <script src="plugin/markdown/markdown.js"></script>
        <script src="plugin/highlight/highlight.js"></script>
        <script src="plugin/zoom/zoom.js"></script>
        
        
        <script>
            // More info about initialization & config:
            // - https://revealjs.com/initialization/
            // - https://revealjs.com/config/
            Reveal.initialize({
                hash: true,

                dependencies: [
                    {
                        src: 'node_modules/reveal_external/external/external.js',
                        condition: function() {
                            return !!document.querySelector( '[data-external],[data-external-replace]' );
                        }
                    },

                ],

                plugins: [ RevealZoom, RevealNotes, RevealMarkdown, RevealHighlight ],

                // Learn about plugins: https://revealjs.com/plugins/
                

            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>

I've tried changing path format, deploying branch with only the dist folder, maybe the solution or answer is quite obvious but I've been unable to ckack it.
I am quite new to all this, specially the concept of a deploy so it's quite the predicament.
UPDATE:
I tried deploying with the external plugin in the plugins folder, also changing the path to avoid the path to node_modules, locally in the development server works fine, deployed shows the same error, therefore i assume in all attempts the plugin is at least included.

The node_modules folder gets created during the build/deployment process, usually via a tool like npm. Did you perform this step on your github space? (Not sure if you can perform it there; if not, you will have to upload that folder and its contents manually.)

I did not, but experimenting a little bit it seem the plugin its correctly implemented, at least external is looking for something. In my last attempt I tried using it not as node_module but as a plugin in the plugin folder, same result.

Well this is kind of awkard, but I hope it helps anybody with a similar problem.
The problem, as C3roe pointed out, boiled down to the external plugin being implemented as a node dependency, it wasn't at least not correctly, the solution    basically is to include external as a plugin.

After that the path tittle game trouble, not sure why it was the only one to not render in the github page. If i had to guess i'd say it is some kind of reserved word? Something like that.
Anyway, it's solved, thx.
